# Plotly: How to set a minimum value on secondary y-axis?

Tags: r, graph, plotly, axis-labels, r-plotly

I want to set a minimum value on the secondary y-axis. This is my code :

```
library(plotly)

# my data
value <- c(300000,400000,500000,600000,500000,600000)
x1 <- c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
x2 <-c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
name <- c("martin","john","marc","igor","thea","julia")
df <- data.frame(value, x1, x2, name)


# graph with plotly
graph=df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~name) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~x1,
           name = "bar1") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~x2,
           name = "bar2") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~value,
            name = "line",
            yaxis = "y2") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "bar",
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right"),
         barmode = "bar",
         legend = list(x = 1.1, y =1))

# showing graph
  graph
```

and i get this :
[image]

but i want the secondary y-axis start at 200k (or 100k) instead of 300k.

How can we fix it ? Some help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you've already got a `fig` set up:

```
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis2 = list(range = c(<min>, <max>)))
```

And in your specific case:

```
graph <- graph %>% layout(yaxis2 = list(range = c(200000,600000)))
```

#### Plot

[image]

### Complete code:

```
library(plotly)

# my data
value <- c(300000,400000,500000,600000,500000,600000)
x1 <- c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
x2 <-c(3,4,5,5,4,3)
name <- c("martin","john","marc","igor","thea","julia")
df <- data.frame(value, x1, x2, name)


# graph with plotly
graph=df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~name) %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~x1,
           name = "bar1") %>% 
  add_bars(y = ~x2,
           name = "bar2") %>%
  add_lines(y = ~value,
            name = "line",
            yaxis = "y2") %>% 
  layout(barmode = "bar",
         yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                       side = "right"),
         barmode = "bar",
         legend = list(x = 1.1, y =1))

# showing graph
#graph

graph <- graph %>% layout(yaxis2 = list(
      #scaleanchor = "x",
      #scaleratio = 0.2,
      range = c(200000,600000)
      #title = "1:5"
      ))
graph
```